# Why tableview doesn't display my array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In previous View controller i have displayed multiple prescription title. after click on particular cell,it goes to next view and call to server like following:

```
::

::    
[manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Response from view Prescription server  :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        NSArray *ResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: kNilOptions error: nil];

        if (ResponseArray.count >0)
        {
            self.menuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:ResponseArray];
           }
             NSLog(@"menu_itemes: %@",_menuItems);
```

I got following Response in menu_items:

```
menu_itemes: (
        {
        bp = "000/000";
        dateTime = "05/12/2016 01:02:59 PM";
        doc =         {
            "email_id" = "batra@gmail.com";
            exception = 0;
            gender = Male;
            id = 0;
            "mobile_no" = 8055621745;
            name = Batra;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            qualification = "MD(Doctor)";
            "reg_id" = 157;
            salutation = Mr;
            "wellness_id" = 251215782521;
        };
        "follow_up" = 17;
        id = 37;
        medicine =         (
            "Syrup,Decold Total,20,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
            "Injection,Insulin,1,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no,
            no
        );
        patient =         {
            "email_id" = "bishtrohit1989@gmail.com";
            exception = 0;
            gender = Male;
            id = 0;
            "mobile_no" = 8055621745;
            name = Rohit;
            "profile_id" = 0;
            qualification = "";
            "reg_id" = 150;
            salutation = Mr;
            "wellness_id" = 290119935030;
        };
        weight = 000;
    }
)
```

I want to display that data like following:

[image]

For that, i tried like following:

I have taken `UITableView` on screen for this.

I have taken 1 static custom cell for this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
  //  return self.menuItems.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *content = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"content = %@",content);

    ViewPrescriptionTableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PatientDetail" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.datetime setText:[content valueForKey:@"dateTime"]];

    [cell.doctorname setText:[[content objectForKey:@"doc"]valueForKey:@"name"]];



    return cell;

}
```

But it does not display anything.

i got `null` at

```
NSLog(@"content = %@",content);
```

when i give `numberOfRowsInSection` is 1,then `cellForRow` called... and when i write `menuItems.count` then `cellForRow` wouldn't be called.

I didn't get that, where i am wrong.

Please anyone can solve my issue. help will be appreciable.

Comment: Place breakpoint on this line: `NSLog(@"content = %@",content);` and check if array is not empty.

Comment: if (ResponseArray.count >0)
        {
            self.menuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:ResponseArray];
           }
             NSLog(@"menu_itemes: %@",_menuItems); in this , i got response which is correct.

Comment: OK, but check you array again in cellForRowAtIndexPath: again.

Comment: @above ::well menu items must be 1+ or the cellForRow wouldnt be called.. !? except if the code shown - isnt the one producing nil. maybe menuItems is weak or set to nil or emptied by you between the two calls. try what timur proposed :)

Comment: and the title has NOTHING to do with your question.. your question seems to be only: 'tableview doesnt display my array of dictionaries'

Comment: GUESS - I think, you are missing [self tableView] reloadData]; in your POST reponse!

Comment: side note: you really ought to get the content dictionary with `[self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, not `0`.  And you'll provide a HUGE help debugging and help to everyone here by logging the array menuItems at that same point. Post that result here, and definitely post how that array is being declared.

Comment: are you getting same error again?

Comment: i update my requirement, please see output image in question...your help will be appreciable ..@PiyushRathi

Comment: @Daij-Djan when i give numberOfRowsInSection is 1,then cellForRow  called... and when i write menuItems.count then cellForRow wouldn't be called.

Comment: @SurajSukale how you declare `menuItems` object in your `.h` file? Also put break point whether tableView datasource method called first or you will receive response first

Comment: issue solved.. :) thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `self.menuItems` is getting reset to nil somewhere. You can write a setter method for `menuItems` and keep the break point in the setter method to check which piece of code is modifying.

Comment: Another guess (better one actually) is @Daij-Djan guess that the array is declared `weak`.  I think answers on this should wait until the OP supplies more info.